# SecondaryTable annotation is working locally but not on test environment

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

So we are in Java 8 (v202 on test env, 230 to 301 locally) and we use spring boot 1.5.4.RELEASE / hibernate (5.0.12) / jpa 2.1.

We have a class like this:

```
@Entity
@SecondaryTable(name = "FOO_BAR")
@org.hibernate.annotations.Table(appliesTo = "foo_bar", optional = false)
@DiscriminatorValue(MyEnum.Values.MY_DISCRIMINATOR)
public class FooBar extends FooBarParent{

@Column(name = "COLUMN_NAME_OF_PRIMARY_TABLE_FOR_FIELD_A")
private Long FIELD_A;

@Column(table= "FOO_BAR", name = "COLUMN_NAME_OF_SECONDARY_TABLE_FOR_FIELD_B")
private String FIELD_B;
```

The script for secondary table is:

```
CREATE TABLE FOO_BAR
(
    ID                            NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
    TOTO                          VARCHAR2(10)
);

ALTER TABLE FOO_BAR
    ADD CONSTRAINT FK_FOO_BAR_PARENT FOREIGN KEY (ID) REFERENCES FOO_BAR_PARENT(ID);
```

This whole inheritance system is working well, but we recently added the secondary table annotation. It is working locally: on adding a FooBar in the database, it adds a row in the secondary table.
On reading another child of FooBarParent (let's call it FooBar2), it's also working locally, it doesn't care about the secondary table which concerns FooBar and not FooBar2.

It's also working locally for my coworker.
It's also working locally with the database of the Test Environment, so even the data is the same, it's working.

But as soon as we test in our Test environments (actually, on all test environments), the code is not working anymore. It's like a heisenbug as we cannot debug it ...

The unexpected result in Test environments is that when you try to read a list of FooBar2, it will produce duplicates. So you will read as many FooBar2 as there is rows in the SecondaryTable. Which is stupid since it's not even supposed to look in there in the first place since it's a secondary table for FooBar not FooBar2.

We assume it's doing a left join or something like that.

adding the

```
@org.hibernate.annotations.Table(appliesTo = "foo_bar", optional = false)
```

didn't help.
We also tried with an other column name and

```
@SecondaryTable(name = "FOO_BAR", pkJoinColumns = {@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "OTHER_COLUMN_NAME_IN_FOO_BAR_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")})
```

We also tried by not having a primary key that is also a foreign key, same.

Result is always the same, working locally, not after.

So we are starting to think maybe it's an issue with hibernate version or properties linked to hibernate which might change from local, or the version of the jvm...

Anyone has an idea?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found out, the issue was that locally we were using a property:

spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect

On the 19 oracle DB.

The property was not used on other environments.